# check if the payment is for renewing the order in woocommerce subscriptions

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i use the [woocommerce subscriptions](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/) plugin

when the user wants to renew their subscription, a text will be displayed on the checkout page, display the text only for the user who is renewing the subscription, do not display it for the user who registers the order for the first time

thank you for taking the time to answer my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ( wcs_get_order_type_cart_items( 'renewal' ) ) {
 // write your text here
}
```